# QGIS 3: Need to bind "Deactivate Label(selected layer)" and "Deactivate all labels", is there a standard/customary setting for them?

Tags: qgis-3, shortcuts

I find it indispensable to have a keyboard shortcut for the **Deactivate Label(selected layer)** and **Deactivate all labels** commands.

I'm considering binding them to **Ctrl+E** and **Shift+Ctrl+E** respectively because as of now it's the one letter in "labEl" still not bound by default.

But since I'm not completely sure these combinations aren't already supposed to work some way or another, I thought I'd ask for your opinion because I've also heard stories about QGIS sometimes getting touchy about customized keyboard shortcuts. Especially bearing in mind these commands belong to the *Deactivate Active Labels* plugin and aren't part of "normal" QGIS. Couldn't tell whether those stories are accurate, though.

I'm aware there's a "Show Label" command in the individual layer's contextual menu, but I can't find that command in the key binding menu. Nevertheless, if possible, I'd rather bind this command since it doesn't depend on a plugin. For the "De/Activate all labels", though, I think the plugin is the only alternative.

Is there an established best practice on this?

I'm using version 3.28.6